# Why is this symbol undefined for architecture x86_64 when the rest of the library loaded fine?

Tags: c++, cmake, include

I'm trying to use an [open source library](https://github.com/mackron/dr_libs/) to read wav/mp3 files in c++, but can't get it to compile when I try to use the init function for said library. When I run `cmake --build . --config Release` I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_drwav_init_file", referenced from:
      _main in audiotests.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

My run code is incredibly simple at the moment, just trying to interact with this library at all to begin with.

```
#include "dr_libs/dr_wav.h"
...

int main()
{
    drwav m_wavFile;
    drwav_init_file(&m_wavFile, "song.wav", NULL);
}
```

And yet I can't compile this. It fails to build every-time. I must be missing something super obvious... thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the library you are using:

> This is a single file library. To use it, do something like the following in one .c file.
>
> ```
> #define DR_WAV_IMPLEMENTATION
> #include "dr_wav.h"
> ```

Looks like you are missing that one. This is a common technique to bundle implementations in one translation unit, and keeping the header (`dr_wav.h` in this case) clean from these definitions.

Comment: oh that's annoying. Guess I gotta read more carefully next time... thanks. I guess this is something to look out for in the future